# Cube in Analysis View not showing in Saiku Analytics

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I installed saiku plugin 2.5 for pentaho 4.8.
followed the instructions [here](http://interestingittips.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/complete-pentaho-installation-on-ubuntu-part-3/) - Extracted Saiku to `biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system`. 
I then followed the instructions in the readme file

```
delete the following JAR files from saiku/lib/
- mondrian*.jar, olap4j*.jar, eigenbase*.jar (should be 1 mondrian, 2 olap4j, 3 eigenbase jar files)
- open saiku/plugin.spring.xml and remove the following line (about line #33):
......
        <property name="datasourceResolverClass" value="org.saiku.plugin.PentahoDataSourceResolver" />
.....

restart your server or use the plugin adapter refresh in http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Admin
thats it!
```

I created a cube using Schema workbench. 
a very simple cube

```
<Schema name="S1">
  <Cube name="Scott1" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="EMP" schema="SCOTT" alias="">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="DEPTNO" name="Departments">
      <Hierarchy name="Name" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Table name="DEPT" schema="SCOTT" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="name" visible="true" column="DNAME" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="employees" column="EMPNO" aggregator="count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <Measure name="Avg Salary" column="SAL" aggregator="avg" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Now, I was able to publish the cube and view it in the Analysis View. The problem is I cant see in the Siaku Analysis window. There is nothing in the cube selection drop-down.

So I tried several things (some of them mentioned in [this post](http://ask.analytical-labs.com/questions/275/saiku-pentaho-i-can-not-see-my-cube?sort=votes&page=1))

- Restarted my bi server.
- Flushed mondrian cache.
- Moved my schema xml file to a new folder named Cube `pentaho-solutions\Haki\cube`.
- Moved my entry to the top of the resources list in `datasources.xml`.

Nothing. 
I would appreciate any guidance.

Windows 7, pentaho 4.8 stable build 5 , saiku plugin 2.5 , oracle 10g.

Comment: Err, did you click the refresh icon in saiku itself?  Also check the log there should be something in there. Saiku has its own mondrian version so maybe for some reason it doesnt like the cube?

Comment: I clicked refresh. saiku is installed as a plugin and has no folder in WEB-INF/APP so where is there a log for it ? (i'm only looking in the tomcat log...)

Comment: yeah should appear in the standard tomcat log

Comment: scrolling up a bit I can see an error `07:59:45,799 ERROR [PentahoDatasourceManager] org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 41 of document  : Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence. Nested exception: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 seq
uence.`. this is all there is for this error. what file is he referring to ?

Comment: @Codek, part of the readme file is to delete mondrian.jar from saiku so he should use the same version as the bi server.

Comment: Add CTools into your BI server, your problem will resolve automatically and you will get to know some other things also.

Comment: @Working Hard I see that ctools requires cygwin & wget. is wget comes with the cygwin ? if not, where can i download it for windows ( i found sites from 2008 ... )

Answer (score 0):

Try this two things:

- Check the logs to see if there are any problems with the cubes.
- Refresh the cube in Saiku. It seems that the Saiku plugin has it's own caché.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial fix for this. Note this might break things, particularly if using Mongo DB.

https://github.com/buggtb/pentaho-mondrian4-plugin/blob/master/utils/EEOSGILIBS-0.1.zip

grab that

unzip it and then copy out the mondrian jar from

pentaho-solutions/system/osgi/bundles

save it somewhere in case this breaks everything.
then copy the jar in that zip file into the same directory
remove the contents of pentaho-solutions/system/osgi/cache/

restart the server

You should now be able to see your EE data sources. Thanks to TB for this solution.